# How to install into a sub folder using WiX 3.11

Tags: c#, xml, windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to get the Wix installer to install into a subfolder.

Here is the code I have to make install into it's current directory:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Workplace"/>
```

The current Destination Folder is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Workplace

I want the Destination Folder to be C:\Program Files (x86)\Workplace\Destination

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the elements.

```xml
<Directory Id="TopLevelDirectory" Name="Workplace">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Destination" />
</Directory>
```

Or use the name shortcut syntax.

```xml
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Workplace\Destination" />
```

Comment: When nesting the elements, it just creates a folder outside of the "workplace" directory called "destination" and installs there. With the other method, it gives an error saying it is invalid

Comment: The 2nd might need to be `ProgramFilesFolder:Workplace\Destination`. I gathered that info from the [Directory](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v4/reference/wxs/directory/) wix docs.

Comment: How would I format that? It gives me an error when I try to use non ASCII characters. I do have "ProgramFilesFolder" in a DirectoryId above that

Comment: Oh sorry. That was a link to WiX v4. You can just do the nested ones. That's what I do for my WiX projects.

Comment: When I try to do the nested, it ignores whatever I have above and just creates a folder with the same name outside of the directory called Destination. So for example, when I try this: <Directory Id="TopLevelDirectory" Name="Workplace">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Destination" />
</Directory>                                       the directory it goes to is ProgramFiles(x86)\Destination. However I want it to go to ProgamFiles(x86)\Workplace\Destination

Comment: It could be a problem in another area of your fragment. Check this [sample](https://github.com/deepak-rathi/Wix-Setup-Samples/blob/master/1.%20Wix%20Simple%20Setup/Wix%20Simple%20Setup/Product.wxs). It shows nesting as well.